# Google sheets - conditional formatting multiple text values

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Seraching for solution with google sheets conditional formatting where I have range with some **text** from dropdown list and I want that I can change text color even there is set cond.formatting.

For example:
I have cell range A1:B20 where I've set if there is mentioned text "John", then it become red according to con.formatting , but I want to be able to set text to some other color from formating menu.

Tried many suggestions from internet, but no luck! Tired :)

Answer (score 1):

without script, you would need to pre-program it for each color. for example...

red:

```
=(A1="John")*($D$2="red")
```

green:

```
=(A1="John")*($D$2="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,

I guess that I will need to use some script, because this is not exactly what I'm looking for.

The color of the text changes to what is written in the formula, but it changes for the whole region and not for a specific cell, if you know what I mean :)